# UITableview listing items issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have settings option where there is a tableview (1) will show "Category" and by selecting the category will show "Sub Category" in next table view.

I have two separate arrays for category and sub category. In "Category" I have @"Business" and @"Personal" (preloaded) and in "Sub Category" at index 0 a list of 10 items relating business and at index 1 set of 10 items relating personal.

By tapping either business or personal it shows the saved sub category list with no issue. 
From here user can add their own category and sub category from the table view.

For instance if I enter a new category named @"All" is added, @"All" gets placed in index 2

"Category" table view shows @"Business" @"Personal" @"All" by selecting the Business or Personal it shows desired the sub category items from index 0 (10 items pre loaded) for Business, index 1 (10 items pre loaded) for personal and index 3 (empty list) for All (users can add their own).

When I use "NSSortDescriptor" for category array

```
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [arrCategory sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Now "Category" table view list as @"All"  @"Business" @"Personal" so "Sub Category" list becomes mismatched. For @"Business" I have sub category of 10 items after sorting list of 10 items for business comes for @"All" category. Index path of category items changes after using "NSSortDescriptor" so sub category becomes mis matched.

How to change the "Sub Category" (items) index matching "Category" after using "NSSortDescriptor" for category ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create models and use the common data source

```
@interface CategoryModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *subCategories; //should contain subCategory class objects
/* all other properties */

@end

@interface subCategory : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *name;
/* all other properties */
@end
```